# how to add changes from future commits after checking out to older commit

Tags: git

I have a set of commits on a branch like so:
`[head]A->B->C->D`
and would checkout to commit `C` but would like to review the changes made from `C` to `B` as uncommitted changes. I was wondering how I can do this. I would start out by doing something like this:

- `git checkout <hash of C>`
- `git checkout -b new-branch`
- ...the rest per advice in responses here

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that you want to end up with:

```
B -> C -> D
```

after first starting of with `C -> D` and reviewing the changes from `B`.  We can try the following:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1  # takes us back to B -> C -> D
git reset --soft HEAD~1  # back to C -> D with B's changes being staged
```

Once you review the staged changes and commit from the second step above, you will end up with `B -> C -> D`.